# How do I use EFCore.BulkExtensions in ASP.NET Boilerplate

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, aspnetboilerplate, efcore.bulkextensions

I need to do bulk insert in ASP.NET Boilerplate and I tried to implement EFCore.BulkExtensions after reading https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/4397 .

I installed the latest EFCore.BulkExtensions from nuget into the project and I tried to use doContext as below so that I can use wherever required.

```
public class MyQueryExecutor : IMyQueryExecutor, ITransientDependency
{
    private readonly IDbContextProvider<ModCoreDbContext> _dbContextProvider;

    public MyQueryExecutor(IDbContextProvider<ModCoreDbContext> dbContextProvider)
    {
        _dbContextProvider = dbContextProvider;
    }

    public void BulkImport<T>(IList<T> entities) where T : class
    {
        _dbContextProvider.GetDbContext().BulkInsert(entities);
    }
}

public interface IMyQueryExecutor
{
    void BulkImport<T>(IList<T> entities) where T : class;
}
```

I referenced EFCore.BulkExtensions in the required projects and when I tried to run the project, I am getting an error when execution hit the following line in Startup.cs

```
 app.UseAbp(); //Initializes ABP framework.
```

**Error:**

```
TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.EntityMaterializerSource' from assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=3.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.
```

Actual `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` that is part of the boilerplate framework is 2.2.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to download a lower version of EFCore.BulkExtensions (2.4.7) nuget as the latest version did not support EF 2.2.4

Answer (score 1):

```
DbContext context = CurrentUnitOfWork.GetDbContext<DbContext>();

await context.Users.AddRangeAsync(createdUsers);
await CurrentUnitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Comment: This is not related to BulkExtenstions, so it doesn't answer the question. Also, please always add some explanation when posting code. Code-only answers are likely to be deleted by reviewers because they have little educational value.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a extension method on the IRepository class.
You can take a look at abp's own implementation of EFPLus

[Abp.EntityFrameworkCore.EFPlus](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/059db7626b3642114b7a2ba7d15b6a14304640dd/src/Abp.EntityFrameworkCore.EFPlus/EntityFrameworkCore/EFPlus/AbpEntityFrameworkCoreEFPlusExtensions.cs)

For SqlBulk this would translate to something like

```
public static class RepositoryBulkExtensions
{
    public static async Task BulkInsertAsync<TEntity, TPrimaryKey>(
        this IRepository<TEntity, TPrimaryKey> repository,
        List<TEntity> entities,
        BulkConfig config = null,
        Action<decimal> progress = null)
    where TEntity : Entity<TPrimaryKey>
    {
        Check.NotNull(repository, nameof(repository));
       
        var context = repository.GetDbContext();
        await context.BulkInsertAsync(entities, config, progress);            
    }        
}
```